# Spiderfoot Docker authentication passwd problem

Tags: docker, authentication

Hello I have the problem that I run a **spiderfoot** instance in a docker. Unfortunately it is not possible for me to protect them on my server with a login name and password. It works without Docker, I have created the directory with *./spiderfoot* on my Linux server as described in the documentation with the file *passwd*.

As described in the documentation, I loaded the directory with git clone, built a container and started it. Creating the passwd inside the container was also unsuccessful. Thanks in advance for ideas.
here is the documentation used [spiderfoot documetation](https://www.spiderfoot.net/documentation/).

Answer (score 1):

Try by creating the `passwd` file outside the container, and mounting it using volumes
`-v passwd:/home/spiderfoot/.spiderfoot/passwd`

Comment: Thank you ! This was the solution, quiet weird but now its working!

Answer (score 0):

Mounting a volume with the passwd file was the solution:

-v passwd:/home/spiderfoot/.spiderfoot/passwd

Comment: No need to create an extra answer if there is already an answer that did it for you, just answering the other answer as accepted is good enough! :)